# Activity keeps running?

Tags: android, timer, activity-finish

Hey I've run into a problem with my program. I want to have a layout that contains a timer within a timer, and an exit button. I've completed the timers successfully, but the problem lies within my exit button coding I think.

Here's my code:

```
package com.MyCompany.MyApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.MyCompany.MyApp.R;


public class Class1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener
    {
    Button btn_exit;
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Class2.class);
    Handler handler;
    protected Context context = this;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handler = new Handler();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_class1);


        btn_exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_exit);
        btn_exit.setOnClickListener(this);

        final TextView text4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);

        btn_exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                    finish();


        }
        });

        new CountDownTimer(45000, 1000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 text4.setText("Seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 text4.setText("Time's up!");

                 new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

                     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                     }
                     @Override
                     public void onFinish() {


                         Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Class2.class);
                           startActivity(intent1);}

                  }.start();

             }
          }.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    }
```

When I run the app and watch the timer go all the way down to zero, the second timer kicks in and counts down from three, as it should, and then the program finishes the current activity and switches to the next. this is all fine, but lets say I run the app, watch the timer go down, but decide at any point I want to hit the exit button, even though it exits the screen and finishes the activity, the timer still proceeds to countdown and switch to Class2. How can I stop it from doing that?

Comment: activities has life cycles which is onPause() and onStop(), now on stop is when the activity is about to b killed onpause is when its moved to backstack and not showing on the screen.. so all you do is when either onPause() or onStop() is called you check whether the timer is still counting down then you kill it, easy.. sounds legit? try it.. and let me knw

Comment: Only thing is i need to get some info from a textview in Class1 so I can't exactly destroy it when the timer runs out or when the exit button is pressed. It needs to probably be paused, if the timer runs out, but if the user presses exit, then yes it kills everything, stopping the timer also.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a global Boolean variable like "ThisActivityExits", on your click listener you change the value of the variable and you can create and "if" inside your Timer to stop it.

Comment: I tried something like this

btn_exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
global1 = false;
if(global1 == false)
finish();}});
if(global1 == true){
new CountDownTimer(45000, 1000) {
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
text4.setText("Seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);}

Comment: public void onFinish() {
text4.setText("Time's up!");        
new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
@Override
public void onFinish() {                    
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Class2.class);
startActivity(intent1);}}.start();}}.start();}
else
finish();


after declaring this near the top of my project

public static boolean global1 = true;

Comment: Hey I figured it out, didn't put the if statement actually in the timer like you said. Thanks much.

Comment: Good to see it helped you!